# Agregarle un día a un input de tipo datetime-local

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, date, input

Cordial saludo tengo una duda ya que lo que trato de realizar es agregar un día mas a un input que es de tipo datetime-local lo cual e intentando con JQuery pero solo me funciona si el input es de tipo date quisiera saber como hacer para que me funcione con el de datetime-local
Este es el codigo que tomo de referencia que funcion con date:

```js
$('#checkInDate')[0].valueAsDate = new Date();

    $('#checkInDate').change(function() {
    var date = this.valueAsDate;
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    $('#checkOutDate')[0].valueAsDate = date;
    });

    $('#checkInDate').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Fecha Inico:  <input type="date" id="checkInDate">
Fecha Fin: <input type="date" id="checkOutDate"> <br>
```

Comment: ¿Ese es el código que no funciona?  Muestranos el que no funciona tambien, a mi este me funciona y si cambio a datetime-local tambien.

Comment: Fecha Inico:  <input type="datetime-local" id="checkInDate">
Fecha Fin: <input type="datetime-local" id="checkOutDate"> si pongo mis inputs de esa manera a mi no me funciona

Comment: ¿Que es lo que no funciona?  Quizas no he entendido la pregunta. Si yo pongo esos tipos en el snippet que has creado y cambio la fecha del primer input me cambia correctamente la del segundo... ¿o no te refieres a eso?

Comment: Lo que quiero realizar es que me agregue un día mas en el segundo input lo cual el código funciona perfectamente con el input de tipo date pero cuando lo cambio a datetime-local deja de funcionar no me pone la fecha en el input ni en el primero ni segundo input

Comment: ¿Lo has probado en el snippet que has puesto en tu mismo en la pregunta?  Siento ser pesado, pero a mi me funciona.  Mira aquí tambien a ver si tampoco te funciona: https://jsfiddle.net/v4Lz5dp3/

Comment: Vale, es cosa del navegador... con Chrome no funciona, con Firefox si

Comment: Vale gracias sabes como podría hacer que me funcione con Chrome?

Comment: La verdad es que no, pero prueba de entender esto a ver si te funciona: https://blog.devatlant.com/blog/2018/02/25/how-to-fix-datetime-local-input-in-chrome/

Comment: Aquí tambien dan todo tipo de explicaciones y ejemplos: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

Comment: Vale gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Suerte!  Por lo que veo basicamente se trataria de tratar la fechas con la `T` esa en medio de la `fechaThora` pero eso implica cambios en tu código y la forma en como calculas las cosas supongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mira a ver si te funciona este snippet:

```js
$('#checkInDate').change(function() {
  var date = new Date(checkInDate.value);
  var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();  
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  $('#checkOutDate').val(add_minutes(date, -offset).toISOString().replace("Z",""));
});

var add_minutes =  function (dt, minutes) {
    return new Date(dt.getTime() + minutes*60000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Fecha Inico: <input type="datetime-local" id="checkInDate">
Fecha Fin: <input type="datetime-local" id="checkOutDate"> <br>
```

***Explicación de los cambios realizados:***

1. He eliminado este código sobrante:

   ```
   $('#checkInDate')[0].valueAsDate = new Date();
   $('#checkInDate').change();
   ```
2. El formato del tipo `datetime-local` no es compatible con la función `valueAsDate` asi que he sustituido esto:

   ```
   var date = this.valueAsDate;
   ```

   por esto:

   ```
   var date = new Date(checkInDate.value);
   ```

   para trabajar directamente con el valor proporcionado en el `input` con el id `checkInDate`.
3. He agregado el cálculo del desplazamiento horario obtenida por la función [`getTimezoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset), que devuelve el tiempo en minutos entre la zona UTC y la zona de hora local.

   ```
   var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
   ```
4. Como he explicado antes, no podemos usar valueAsDate, por lo tanto he cambiado esta línea:

   ```
   $('#checkOutDate')[0].valueAsDate = date;
   ```

   por esta otra:

   ```
   $('#checkOutDate').val(add_minutes(date, -offset).toISOString().replace("Z",""));
   ```

   donde:

   *$('#checkOutDate').val()*: Asignará un valor al input `checkOutDate`

   *add_minutes(date, -offset)*: Ejecutará la adición o sustracción de los minutos calculados en `offset`. Mirar la función más abajo.

   *toISOString()*: Convertirá la fecha devuelta por `add_minutes` a formato `UTC 0`

   *replace("Z","")*: Sustraerá la letra `Z` a la cadena devuelta por `toISOString` para que sea compatible con el tipo `datetime-local` que necesitamos usar en el input `checkOutDate`
5. Y por último, he agregado la función `add_minutes` que realiza la suma o resta de minutos de un objeto Date retornando otro objeto Date:  ([enlace al crédito](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-date-exercise-6.php))

   ```
   var add_minutes =  function (dt, minutes) {
       return new Date(dt.getTime() + minutes*60000);
   }
   ```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda si me funciona tu código proporcionado

Comment: No, no lo hace bien... ahí estoy borrando la `Z` sin miramientos y lo que debo hacer es convertir la fecha a la hora local o algo asi, porque la Z indica que es horario UTC y debo variarlo al horario normal... fijate que hay una hora de diferencia entre ambos campos

Comment: Voy a ver si consigo arreglar eso... a mi me muestra una hora menos en el segundo campo... a ti no?

Comment: a mi me muestra 2 horas mas

Comment: es por la diferencia horaria entre tu timezone y la del [meridiano de grenwicth o UTC 0](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zona_hor%C3%A0ria#/media/Fitxer:World_Time_Zones_Map.png)... a mi me sale una hora menos porque estoy en otra zona

Comment: Vale, comprueba de nuevo el snippet, por favor, a ver si ahora te pone bien la hora

Comment: Supongo que debes recargar esta pagina antes para refrescarlo

Comment: Ahora si me pone la fecha y hora correcta te agradezco mucho

Comment: Perfecto! :-)  Luego o mañana lo documentare un poco mas, pues seguro que afecta a mucha gente y les puede servir de ayuda.

Comment: Una ultima consulta disculpa las molestias y si quiero que las horas me salgan por defecto en los inputs como en el primer snippet que doy como ejemplo como lo podría hacer

Comment: Usa un formato asi `value="2017-06-01T08:30:25` en los inputs (o se lo pasas por javascript, pero en ese formato), pero cuando yo lo probe en firefox creo que no me funcionó, aunque si en Chrome. O al reves :-)

Comment: Puedes ahora mirar de pulsar la flecha que hay sobre el 0 al lado de mi respuesta?  es para ver si funciona, porque creo que si no tienes puntuacion no te lo permite... es esa que dice "Esta respuesta es útil" cuando pasas por encima

Comment: Por cierto, he actualizado mi respuesta con una explicación bien amplia, por si te interesa

Comment: Si muchas gracias ya probé en dar la flecha pero me pide mas reputación

Comment: Vale, perfecto, es que tenia esa duda, muchas gracias :-)